# Error in java compiler when Exception in Constructor

Tags: java, exception, compiler-construction, constructor

maybe there is a specialist for java internals.
I have a problem understanding the compiled code for the following java code

```
public class TestException
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        try
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder(null);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException t)
        {

        }
        if (sb != null)
        {
            System.out.print(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This will be compiles to:

```
stack=3, locals=3, args_size=1

 0: aconst_null   
 1: astore_1 
 2: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
 5: dup           
 6: aconst_null   
 7: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
10: astore_1      
11: goto          15
14: astore_2  
15: aload_1       
16: ifnull        29
19: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/OutStream;
22: aload_1       
23: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
26: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/OutStream.print:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
29: return

Exception table:
 from    to  target type
     2    11    14   Class java/lang/NullPointerException
```

My problem:
at line 7, the stack content is

1. ref to StringBuilder instance
2. ref to StringBuilder instance
3. null

After invoking StringBuilder(String) the last two arguments will be removes, so stack contains only

1. ref to StringBuilder instance

This is ok for normal execution, but when having the exception (address 14), stack will look like

1. ref to StringBuilder instance
2. ref to Exception instance

After storing the exception ref in local var 2, so at end of catch, there is still the ref to the stringbuilder left on stack.

Can someone point out where I go wrong?

Thanks,
Gunter

Comment: Is your intention to *not* have the string builder on the stack?  It's still in scope so it should be there.

Comment: please see my comment to the answer below... Gunter

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is expected. You called `new StringBuilder(null)`, then there is an instance of a `StringBuilder`, even if an exception has been thrown.

Of course, this object will never (and cannot) be manipulated, because it has no reference: `sb` is `null`. The garbage collector is going to collect this unused object at any time but the JVM has the control and you cannot predict its behaviour.

Comment: My problem is not the "dead" object. I try to write a jvm and due to this behaviour I encounter problems that the stack grows out of estimated range. (I have written a small test program, where I have this case more than once). The "real" java seems not to be disturbed, if I put that code in an endless loop, it never produces an error...

Comment: I think you must handle this type of problem in your JVM. This is your task since you write it. I don't imagine what else do you expect in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you should have the StringBuilder class on the top of the stack (not an instance of it, just the class).  Make sure you are popping it off in your "return" logic and not somewhere else instead.

Can you post some code?

Comment: Yes.  There are only references to instances.  In this case (as many) i believe it's a reference to a *Class* instance, not a StringBuilder instance.  It really shouldn't matter either way, the idea is that you need to make sure you are consistently popping them off the stack, whether there's an exception or not.

Comment: Hello Ted, to clarify: on the stack there are only references (to instances...). Posting some code (of the VM) seem not very helpful, because this has then to be 80% of the total code of the VM. My problem is, that when there is no failure in my interpretation of the generated java code, there is a special case when processing an exception to "eliminate" the needless reference. When not, stack can grow above the estimated size.